# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET (Session info: headless chrome=86.0.4240.111)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to ChromeDriver, try to work on a crawler here.
I am running Python 3.8.5, Google Chrome 86.0.4240.111, ChromeDriver 86.0.4240.22, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on my laptop.
Here is the selenium part of my code.

```
chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.douyu.com/9999')
for i in cookies.keys():
    cookie1 = {
        'domain': '.douyu.com',
        'name': i,
        'value': cookies[i],
        'expires': '',
        'path': '/',
        'httpOnly': False,
        'HostOnly': False,
        'Secure': False,
    }
    driver.add_cookie(cookie1)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(10)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

When I run the codes on my laptop, everything is fine. But when I connect to the laptop through ssh and then run the codes. I'll bump into this ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and another similar one using WebDriver with C#. After a brief search [this solution](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-err-name-not-resolved-error/) worked for me.
I can't see this as a permanent solution in a production environment since the machine where you are running WebDriver may be sensible to DNS IP change.